# Adobe AIR Mobile / OAuth2.0

Tags: ios, mobile, actionscript, air, oauth-2.0

We are currently trying to add OAuth2.0 for authentication into an existing Adobe AIR mobile app for a client.  We are trying to carry this out by using this library https://github.com/charlesbihis/actionscript-oauth2 from [this article](http://blogs.adobe.com/charles/2012/05/oauth-2-0-library-for-actionscript.html).

We have tried using instances of the 'StageWebView' class and the Feathers UI 'WebView' class to display the authorization prompt page within the mobile app itself.

When we publish the app locally on our development PCs, the whole process works ok.  However, as soon as it is published to our iPad(s) for testing, it is almost as if some security setting stops the "embedded" website from communicating with to the server.

As the website we are trying to communicate with is a https:// address, I'm assuming that this might be causing issues, but I can't confirm this.

Has anyone out there found themselves in a similar situation?

Thanks,

Dave